# High intensity training schedule during vacation

Tags: workout-routines, strength-training, muscle-recovery

I will have **a lot of time available for one week** and I am thinking how to use this for strength training most effectively.

I am used to three training sessions (Mo-Wed-Fri) with weights and gym rings per week (1-2h), with one day in between for recovery. Now that I have a lot of time available for this week, I would like to do more, but I wonder how I can do this most effectively without risking injuries.

- My understanding is that the muscles need the recovery time - does it even make sense to train more?
- Would it make sense to distribute the training over the whole day into short sessions or is training in one go the better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a whole week to strength train and really wanna push yourself.

Train a different muscle every day of the week.

such as:

Monday: back and biceps, shoulders
Tuesday: legs and abs
Wednesday: chest, tris
Thursday: break
then repreat and break again on sunday,
do 30 minutes of cardio before and after.

make sure while your doing these to real push your limits, if you normally only do about 3 sets for one muscle.. do 5 exercises, 3 sets each.